# What does Lightning do to my existing Salesforce Classic automated testing?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

We have automated our Client UI Salesforce application (Classic) using [HP Unified Functional Testing](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/unified-functional-automated-testing/) software... now when Salesforce brings on Lightning objects?

1. Will my scripts work with the lightning objects?
2. Can I still use UFT for automation or do I have to look for some other tool?

Comment: The UI is completely changed so if your scripts depend on something being in a specific position etc then yes it will mess with it. It is easy to try out though. Just turn it on in a sandbox and run your scripts

Comment: @Eric the HP software is a UI testing suite for verifying functional app behavior. Typically used for front-end testing.

Comment: @MarkPond - So it is not Like Selenium where it mimics mouse movement, click, and verify what is shown etc? I did a cursory look at their website so did not get deep into it.

Comment: Yes that's what it is. Just wanted to clarify the typical use case of UFT, since your original comment's body was about backend functionality and the automated testing not changing.

Comment: @MarkPond - Gotcha, yea I made the comment then went wait, what is HP UFT, looked it up then edited my comment. Sorry about that.

Comment: I have experience in automating web applications using HP UFT and selenium and I am 100% confident that you have to rewrite your scripts otherwise your scripts will fail.

Comment: @javanoob that sounds like an answer to me. :-)

Comment: @javanoob - Thank a lot for the info! I have no experience with Selenium... though I knew that I'd have to rewrite my scripts, I was wondering if I could still use UFT with the new lightning objects, or do I have to switch to Selenium ?  Someone at my organization started arguments like 'your UFT is not enough, you'll have to use Selenium..', which I'm ready to agree.  Since you have experience with both tools, please help me.

Comment: Oops...I meant to say, I'm NOT willing to accept the argument that UFT won't be enough, I'll have to switch to Selenium for lightning objects!

Comment: @SarithaBokka, I am a java guy at heart so I will vote for selenium only :). Selenium is very robust and integrates easily with tools like cucumber, soapUI, ant build tool and hudson CI. I haven't tried automating Lightning with webdriver yet but it should be possible. Good luck with your journey on automating lightning with whatever tool you choose :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Abandoned

Answer (score -1):

A bit of an old thread, but if you want a test automation tool which specializes in testing classic and Lightning you should take a look at Provar.  It is not a free application, but has solutions to all the Salesforce testing issues (such as brittle locators, complex frames in Console apps, VisualForce etc.)